# Exportar lista CRUD com MPDF + OB_start()

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, mpdf

Bom dia galera, estou desenvolvendo um `CRM` utilizando o framework `CodeIgniter` e não estou conseguindo realizar a exportação de algumas listas `CRUD` utilizando a biblioteca `MPDF`.

Estou tentando usar a função `ob_start()` conforme indicado no própio manual da biblioteca, mas ao exportar, recebo o seguinte erro como retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo, os códigos utilizados:

view:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="http://localhost/sistema/clientes/inserir" class="btn btn-   primary pull-right h2">Novo Cliente</a>
</div>
```

```
<div id="list" class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Empresa</th>
                    <th>Contato</th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Cidade</th>
                    <th class="actions">Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <?php foreach ( $clientes as $cliente ) {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $cliente->ccod; ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $cliente->cnome; ?></td>    
                        <td><?php echo $cliente->contato; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cliente->telefone; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cliente->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $cliente->cidade; ?> </td>
                        <td class="actions">
                            <a title="history" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'comments/history/' . $cliente->ccod; ?>">Historico</a>
                            <a title="orçamentos" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'orcamentos/history/' . $cliente->ccod; ?>">Orçamentos</a>
                            <a title="Editar" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'clientes/editar/' . $cliente->ccod; ?>"> Editar</a>
                            <a title="Deletar" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'clientes/deletar/' . $cliente->ccod; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Confirma a exclus�o deste registro?')">Deletar</a>
                        </td>       

                    </tr>               

                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="col-sm-12">
    <a href="http://localhost/sistema/clientes/exports" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right h2">Exportar</a>
</div>
```

Estou colocando a função `ob_start()` logo no inicio da view contendo o `HTML` da pagina.

Controler:

```
public function exports(){

    $html= ob_get_contents();

    ob_end_clean(); 

    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "relatorio de clientes.pdf";

    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    //actually, you can pass mPDF parameter on this load() function
    $pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
    //generate the PDF!
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //offer it to user via browser download! (The PDF won't be saved on your     server HDD)
    $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");      
}
```

Além disso, não alterei nada nos arquivos da biblioteca, e complementando, segue um print da tela de onde estou tentando exportar a lista, notem que o que pretendo fazer é só imprimir a lista, a parte de layout e menu não.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou iniciante com `PHP`, não sei se estou colocando a função no local correto do meu código.

Comment: Mostre a `VIEW` completa, por favor.

Comment: Organize as coisas: **Você não vai conseguir fazer a mesma `view` gerar tanto a lista quanto o pdf**. Não da forma que vc quer. Certo, neste caso, é um método gerar a lista, outro gerar o relatório pdf da lista (são duas coisas). Um controlador gera a lista com base nos filtros, não é? Então o botão *Exportar* pode gerar o relatório com base nesses mesmos filtros. É bem mais complexo do que parece...

Comment: Acredito que entendi o que você quis dizer, sim em meu controller eu estou utilizando um método para criar a lista de itens, e um método para exportar, mas tentei aproveitar a mesma view de fato, vou mudar para a forma como indicou e posto o resultado. obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu vou te explicar a ideia, você parte daqui e faz as adaptações que forem necessárias no seu código.

Aqui está a receita básica do nosso *algoritimo*:

1. Mostrar os dados e o *FORM* de filtragem e fazer filtragem;
2. Gerar as listas filtradas mediante requisição;
3. Retornar os valores do banco, conforme o filtro da requisição;
4. Gerar os relatórios filtrados em *PDF* usando *MPDF*;

**OBS:** Eu fiz tudo isso num único *controller*, mas vc pode delegar as funções do *model* na sua aplicação depois. O ideal é que vc entenda a lógica.

**Controller Report.php**:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Report extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);
    }

    function mostra_lista() {
        $data['title'] = 'Mostra lista';
        $data['dados'] = $this->dados();
        $this->load->view('mostra_lista', $data);
    }

    function gera_lista(){
        $data['title'] = 'Gera lista';
        $criterio = $this->input->get('criterio');
        if (empty($criterio)) {
            $data['dados'] = $this->dados();
            $this->load->view('gera_lista', $data);
        }
        else{
            $data['dados'] = $this->dados($criterio);
            $data['criterio'] = $criterio;
            $this->load->view('gera_lista', $data);
        }   
    }

    function gera_pdf() {
        $criterio = $this->input->get('criterio');
        $filename = __FUNCTION__.'.pdf';
        $data['dados'] = $this->dados($criterio);
        $view = $this->load->view('gera_lista', $data);
        $html = $view->output->final_output;
        $this->mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-P');
        $this->mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $this->mpdf->Output($filename,'D');
    }

    private function dados(){
        $dados = [];
        if(empty($this->input->get('criterio'))){
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                $dados[$i] = [
                    'id' => $i,
                    'empresa' => "Empresa $i",
                    'contato' => "Contato $i",
                    'telefone' => "Tel $i",
                    'email' => "email$i@mail.com",
                    'cidade' => "Cidade $i",
                ];
            }
            return $dados;
        }
        else{
            for ($i = 5; $i <= 10; $i++) {
                $dados[$i] = [
                    'id' => $i,
                    'empresa' => "Empresa $i",
                    'contato' => "Contato $i",
                    'telefone' => "Tel $i",
                    'email' => "email$i@mail.com",
                    'cidade' => "Cidade $i",
                ];
            }
            return $dados;
        }
    }

}
```

**View mostra_lista.php**: E esta é, de fato, a parte complicada deste programa. Preste atenção ao `JavaScript`, pois ele é que faz a mágica.

Se você clicar em *Refresh* com o *FORM* vazio, a lista vem completa. Se passar um valor no *FORM*, a lista muda. O link de exportação (que pode ser um botão ou qualquer outra coisa) sempre vai salvar a lista exibida (esse é o comportamento esperado).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                //Carrega a lista completa com a pagina
                mostra_lista();
                // Carrega a lista sob demanda
                $('#fa-refresh').click(function () {mostra_lista();});
                // Altera comportamento padrao do FORM
                $("#gera_lista").submit(function (e) {e.preventDefault();});
            });
            function mostra_lista() {
                //Envia os dados do FORM para o controller
                $.get(
                    $("#gera_lista").attr("action"),
                    $("#gera_lista").serialize(),
                    //Captura a lista filtrada pela requisicao
                    function (resp) {
                        //Altera o parametro de filtragem para o metodo gera_pdf()
                        var criterio = $('#criterio').val();
                        var href = "<?=base_url('report/gera_pdf/')?>?criterio="+criterio;
                        $("a").attr("href", href);
                        //Mostra a lista filtrada
                        $('#resp').html(resp);
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar"></nav>
        <div class="container">
            <form class="form-inline" id="gera_lista" action="<?= base_url('report/gera_lista') ?>">
                <input type="text" name="criterio" id="criterio" class="form-control" placeholder="Critério de busca">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="fa-refresh">Refresh</button>
            </form>
            <br>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <a id="gera_pdf" href="" target="_blank" value="">
                    Exportar lista exibida como pdf
                </a>
                <div id="resp"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**View gera_lista.php**:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$key = !empty($criterio) ? $criterio : '';
?>
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>empresa</td>
            <td>contato</td>
            <td>telefone</td>
            <td>email</td>
            <td>cidade</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if ($dados) {
            foreach ($dados as $item => $arr) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo "<td>{$arr['id']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$arr['empresa']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$arr['contato']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$arr['telefone']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$arr['email']}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$arr['cidade']}</td>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

É isso. Teste, ponha pra funcionar no seu ambiente e acompanhe a lógica que não tem erro.