# Usar um form com select para controlar views

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-3

Boa tarde galera, seguinte não consegui achar uma solução pratica para o que estou tentando desenvolver:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Através do select acima pretendo exibir dados abaixo tais como gráficos, ou seja se o usuário escolher o item gera o gráfico 1, o item 2 gera o gráfico 2

o problema é que eu gostaria que este select fique sempre acima da pagina com os resultados sendo gerados abaixo conforme forem selecionados.

estou utilizando o Codeigniter para o desenvolvimento disto, então possuo um controller chamando esta view e também vou ter um model para extrair os dados do banco e gerar os dado, mas por enquanto gostaria apenas de simular o que estou tentando fazer mais afrente vou gerar os

Comment: Você já viu como fazer isso aqui: [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178137/42307](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178137/42307). É só trocar o `<input>` por um `<select>`.

Comment: usaria algo assim então $variavel = $this->select->get('id_do_select');

Comment: Isso vai depender do seu _MODEL_. Mas é a mesma lógica. Seguindo o procedimento da resposta que eu indiquei vc vai chegar exatamente ao mesmo resultado. Mas ao invés de usar `<input type="text" name="criterio" id="criterio" class="form-control" placeholder="Critério de busca">`, construa um `<select>` com as `<options>` apropriadas.